# How to put value which contain itself a query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to INSERT or UPDATE  "((Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%SWPTotSwapUsedPercent%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%MemUsedPercent%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%MemAvlPct%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%TrueSight%Memory Used%')) OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%Memory Free%'))" this value in SQL

Query :-

```
UPDATE [Scheduler_V3].[dbo].[tbl_Trigger_Fields]
         SET [Value] = '((Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%SWPTotSwapUsedPercent%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and
   Field_Value LIKE '%MemUsedPercent%') OR (Field_Name = 'description'
   and Field_Value LIKE '%MemAvlPct%') OR (Field_Name = 'description'
   and Field_Value LIKE '%TrueSight%Memory Used%')) OR (Field_Name =
   'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%Memory Free%'))'
         WHERE  [Field_ID] ='F58AD8ED-B481-4416-A2FF-2B4A4AEC952A
```

'

Comment: Hard to understand. Are you asking, how to save apostrophes into chracter fields or what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [Scheduler_V3].[dbo].[tbl_Trigger_Fields]
SET [Value] = '((Field_Name = ''description'' and Field_Value LIKE ''%SWPTotSwapUsedPercent%'') OR (Field_Name = ''description'' and
Field_Value LIKE ''%MemUsedPercent%'') OR (Field_Name = ''description''
and Field_Value LIKE ''%MemAvlPct%'') OR (Field_Name = ''description''
and Field_Value LIKE ''%TrueSight%Memory Used%'')) OR (Field_Name =
''description'' and Field_Value LIKE ''%Memory Free%''))'
WHERE  [Field_ID] ='F58AD8ED-B481-4416-A2FF-2B4A4AEC952A'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have a built-in boolean type.  This is often handled using a `case` expression to assign `0` (for false) and `1` (for true).  So I would expect something like:

```
. . .
set value = (case when <complicated expression here> then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: I just only need to put the value "((Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%SWPTotSwapUsedPercent%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%MemUsedPercent%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%MemAvlPct%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%TrueSight%Memory Used%') OR (Field_Name = 'description' and Field_Value LIKE '%Memory Free%'))" in Value column ..